# Create a directory set of files to multiple zips?

Tags: java, zip

I want to convert my directory(i.e. too large) which i want to convert to multiple zip files . Right now i can able to convert all files in the dirctory to one zip file using the below code .

```
package bulkimport;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class Tzip {
   static final int BUFFER = 2048;
   public static void main (String argv[]) {
      try {
         BufferedInputStream origin = null;
         FileOutputStream dest = new 
           FileOutputStream("D:/abc/file.zip");
         ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new 
           BufferedOutputStream(dest));
         //out.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED);
         byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
         // get a list of files from current directory
         File f = new File("D://current//");
         String files[] = f.list();

         for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Adding: "+files[i]);
            FileInputStream fi = new 
              FileInputStream("D://current//"+files[i]);
            origin = new 
              BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(files[i]);
            out.putNextEntry(entry);
            int count;
            while((count = origin.read(data, 0, 
              BUFFER)) != -1) {
               out.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            origin.close();
         }
         out.close();
      } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

What i need to do to above code in such a way that it will create multiple zip files based on our condition(i.e.By setting threshold as 50MB it will create multiple zip files of each file having 50MB of compressed data )

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Is the limiting the size of the files going in (in contains up 50mb of uncompressed data) or the size of the compressed file?

Comment: @MadProgrammer It is the size of files going in (in contains up 50mb of uncompressed data) . Updated in my question too.

Comment: Conceptually, I'd start by sorting the file list in size order.  Then trying to group the files into batches of `50mb`, for example, starting with the larger files, see how many smaller files you can group with it. Once you have the groups, then I'd simply compress the group into a separate file